# How to reset position of View to undo TranslateAnimation?

Tags: android, android-animation

This method

```
animation.setFillAfter(false);
```

doesn't reset view's position.

Also, the methods

```
getLocationInWindow(), getLocationOnScreen(), getMatrix()
```

produce the same result before animation starts and after animation ends.
What properties of a `View` does `TranslateAnimation` change?

Answer (score 1):

> How to reset position of View to undo TranslateAnimation?

You can reset the view state into it's default using the following.

```
imageView.clearAnimation()
```